# Не работает XnviewMP в Debian/LXDE

Tags: linux, debian, lxde

Вот немогу заставить работать XnviewMP под Debian/LXDE. Скачал .deb  и поставил его через dpkg -i, он появился в разделе "Графика", но при нажатии на ярлык ничего не происходит , с Debian первый опыт по сути, но в принципе с Unix дело имел, в OSX удобно было отлаживать проблемы через Opensnoop, но тут как я понимаю нужен другой подход.

Comment: В первую очередь попытайтесь запустить его через терминал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем оказалось ему не хватает либы libgstapp-0.10.so.0 из libgstreamer, сделал

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10
```

и всё заработало